# How to apply this css for move element text "`DOG DOG DOG`" to top over `cat` image?

Tags: html, css

How to apply this css for move element text "`DOG DOG DOG`" to top over `cat` image ?

i test in chrome it's ok

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/g53/BwHNe9.png

but in ie7 element text `DOG DOG DOG` not move to top `cat` image

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/53f/8OqTpZ.png

how to apply css ?

```
<div style=" display: block;
opacity: 1;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
float: left;
background: #fff;
margin: 7px;">
<div style="
    left: 25px;  top: 13px;  z-index: 999;  opacity: 1;  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  color: #fff;  font-weight: bold;  width: 117px;  text-align: center;  font-size: 12px;  font-family: lato;  padding: 10px 0px;  position: absolute;  margin: 0px;  background-color: rgb(0, 178, 45);  -moz-border-radius: 6px;  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;  border-radius: 6px ;
">
    DOG DOG DOG
</div>
<img src="http://green.uwex.edu/files/2010/06/4-H-Dog.png" width="80" height="80" style=" border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203); ">            
</div>






<div style=" display: block;
opacity: 1;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
float: left;
background: #fff;
margin: 7px;">
<div style="
    left: 25px;  top: 13px;  z-index: 999;  opacity: 1;  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  color: #fff;  font-weight: bold;  width: 117px;  text-align: center;  font-size: 12px;  font-family: lato;  padding: 10px 0px;  position: absolute;  margin: 0px;  background-color: rgb(0, 178, 45);  -moz-border-radius: 6px;  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;  border-radius: 6px;
">
    CAT CAT CAT
</div>
<img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120908225005/disney/images/thumb/b/b6/Cheshirecatdisney.png/256px-Cheshirecatdisney.png" width="80" height="80" style=" border: 1px solid rgb(203, 203, 203); ">            
</div>
```

Comment: What about using `z-index` for the divs? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp and on that website, a link to this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_z-index&preval=2

Comment: I also have a question. Your text overlaps the other text elements, I'm not sure if this is the desired output. What are your intentions with the code you've provided? There may be a better way of doing what you are attempting to do. You should also separate your HTML code from your styles and create a CSS document with all your styles attached.

Comment: Separate your HTML and CSS like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/tastbez8/

Comment: ctwheels   ----- ie7 not work ^^

Comment: I know, I simply posted the jsfiddle so that it is cleaner for others looking to help you, as well as myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
now check work fine in ie 7...  in body tag first div you change the css 


<div style=" display: block;
opacity: 1;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
*position: absolute; /* for ie 7 only */
float: left;
background: #fff;
margin: 7px;">
```